# Update cells of a table output in terminal in Java

Tags: java, terminal

I am writing a java program that will run tasks in parallel, which I want to report the status of each task in a table in terminal as it is running. so i would I have something like:

```
TaskName|StartTime|EndTime

Task1   |12:20    |23:56

Task2   |12:23    |--:--

Task3   |--:--    |--:--
```

And as each task is kicked off and finished, the table would update in place...
Is there any easy way to do this in Java? I saw some answers about using \r instead of \n (probably hard for multiline purposes), or using Java Curses library (which i cannot find any documentation on).

Any pointer is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [CHARVA](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/), but it's a little old (latest release: 09/11/2006). It should do the job though.

Comment: cool thanks. I was looking into \r usage more, is there any way that I can overwrite entire line? (like not having junk left over if my line is shorter than the previous line)

Comment: @Bob I haven't really tried doing console stuff in Java. I think something like CHARVA would be the best bet since it's a library and it will abstract out a lot of that logic out for you.

Comment: thanks for your help! I ended up finding solution similar to \r, except to support mutiline I include control characters to move up a line and to clear line

Comment: Hey @Bob, no harm in answering your own question here since it sounds like your solution was different than Vivin mentioned. You never know when someone else might be looking for the same information that you know ;)